# Strange output after insert data in mongo database

Tags: php, mongodb

I got a strange output when I insert an array to mongoDB. Here is array which I'm inserting:

```
Array
(
    [category_id] => Array
        (
            [id] => -5235252552
            [name] => TestCategory
        )
    [data1] => D01
    [data2] => I
    [data3] => 0
)
```

The way how I do that is:

```
  $mongo->db->selectCollection($mongoTable)->insert(
                                    array(
                                      $data,
                                    )
                                );
```

And here is output in database which I got:

```
array (
  '_id' => new MongoId("53478c1eea1522a3777059b3"),
  '0' => // This don't needs to be here''
  array (
    'category_id' => 
    array (
      'id' => '-5235252552',
      'name' => 'TestCategory',
    ),
    'data1' => 'D01',
    'data2' => 'I',
    'data3' => '0',
  ),
)
```

As you can see I got strange key in my database and I don't need that. So, zero ('0') don't needs to be there. The result in database which I would like to get is:

```
array (
  '_id' => new MongoId("53478c1eea1522a3777059b3"),
  'category_id' => 
    array (
      'id' => '-5235252552',
      'name' => 'TestCategory',
    ),
    'data1' => 'D01',
    'data2' => 'I',
    'data3' => '0',
  ),
)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inserted array, so change it to

```
$mongo->db->selectCollection($mongoTable)->insert($data);
```

And you'll get correct output. The key is special mongoDB object, it is required and auto-generated.

Comment: Add one space to have the code line formatted nice.

Comment: Yes, but when I try do to on that way I got this error:

exception 'MongoException' with message ''.' not allowed in key: 05.11 MÅTT BREDD, VÄGGÖPPNING (mm)' in /data/www/html/dev/components/com_door/helpers/migrate.php:120 Stack trace: #0 /data/www/html/dev/components/com_door/helpers/migrate.php(120): ......

Comment: As you can see above I write just example. In my first post are not real key and values. Maybe keys in mongoDB can't contain special characters VÄGGÖPPNING and can't start with number if I want to put them at the root level...

Comment: Yes, i think they are.

Comment: If you try it in the mongo shell (thus in JavaScript), the important bit is to use { 'key': foo } instead of { key: foo } if the key is starting with a number or has special characters. No idea how to repeat this via the PHP driver though.

Answer (score 0):

Your insert wrapped it into an array(), so MongoDB is right. Do not wrap, just insert $data.

Comment: Most certainly right, but could do with a little more explanation, such as example of how both forms serialize.

Comment: You inserted array($data) instead of just $data.

Answer (score 0):

As a further example, even though MongoDB adds the `_id` value for you, what you have done is effectively this:

```
$data = array(
  '_id' => "123", array(
  'category_id' => array(
      'id' => '-5235252552',
      'name' => 'TestCategory',
  ),
  'data1' => 'D01',
  'data2' => 'I',
  'data3' => '0',
));

echo json_encode( $data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT ) ."\n";
```

That is just to show you what happens. So again without adding in the `_id` you want yout data to be this:

```
$data = array(
  '_id' => "123",
  'category_id' => array(
      'id' => '-5235252552',
      'name' => 'TestCategory',
  ),
  'data1' => 'D01',
  'data2' => 'I',
  'data3' => '0',
);

echo json_encode( $data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT ) ."\n";
```

So when you are adding to mongo just do this:

```
$mongo->db->selectCollection($mongoTable)->insert($data):
```

And then everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$m = new MongoClient("localhost");
```

$datab = $m->selectDB("Testing");
$collection = $datab->selectCollection("Users");
//Insert data here
$datab = $collection->insert($data, array('$data' => 1));
$results = $collection->find();

foreach($results as $test) {
    print_r($test);
}